# CSS column structure

Tags: css

I am developing a new template trying my hand at some CSS3 and HTML5 techniques...

Having a small issue... when i inspect this page using FireBug, i can see that my lef column and right column are not being encased into the #container div. And i realize that I am floating them both left...but cant figure out what i need to do to get them wrapped in the container div....

Here is the HTML: (link to page in case that is easier) http://www.bcidaho.com/dev-acn/index.asp

```
    <body>

  <div id="container">

    <!--#include file="_includes/top-nav-header.asp"--> 

    <!--#include file="_includes/home-nav.asp"-->


        <div id="left-col">
            <p>Lef Nav Column</p>
        </div><!-- End #left-col -->

        <div id="main-col">
            <p>Main Column</p>
        </div><!-- End #main-col -->


  </div> <!--! end of #container -->

    <!--#include file="_includes/footer.asp"-->
</body>
```

CSS is located here: (didnt want to throw a ton of css on this post sorry) http://www.bcidaho.com/dev-acn/css/style.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are being incased. In firebug it doesn't look like it because their floats aren't being cleared. Add this to your css:

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

and after:

```
<div id="left-col">
            <p>Lef Nav Column</p>
        </div><!-- End #left-col -->

        <div id="main-col">
            <p>Main Column</p>
        </div><!-- End #main-col -->
<div class="clear"></div>
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

add `overflow: hidden;`, `overflow: auto;`, or `float: left;` to div#container

Comment: If i add: float:left; that kills the layout and pushes the container left... but i still see your point.

Comment: @tony That's why I said "or". There is more than one solution.

Answer (score 0):

apply `overflow:hidden` to "container"